# Signing exe with certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, pki

i have got a certificate in .cer extension from our company's  Windows PKI server (infrastructure).

Now i want to manually sign an exe file with this certificate. But Microsoft signtool only allows pfx file to sign the exe file i guess.

So, i wanted to convert the .cer file into .pfx file using openssl tool and the  command i issued was

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile more.crt
```

But my question is how do i get the privateKey.key file or how do i have to generate it ?

Is my procedure to sign an exe file correct ?

**Update**

Did some reading on the whole Windows server PKI infra and CertTool.
I have the .cer file with private key.
But not able to locate it somehow.

But was able to sign my exe with this certificate using DigiCertUtil.exe

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: On Windows the private key should be in a certificate store. Run `mmc.exe`, add the Certificates snap-in, locate the certificate, and then export the private key.

Comment: but how do i export the key of a .cer file ?

Answer (score 2):

`signtool` can sign with a privatekey and certificate from the Windows certificate "store" (shown as an entry for a certificate WITH a private key) or from a PFX/P12 file (which contains a privatekey and certificate(s)). The common theme is that you **use the privatekey** as well as the certificate to sign, or decrypt; a certificate alone contains only the publickey and is not sufficient. The whole point of public-key cryptography is that only the privatekey "owner", or someone given a copy, can sign or decrypt; the publickey can be distributed publicly and used to verify or encrypt, but no one else can use the publickey to obtain the privatekey so the privatekey remains private. If you could 'generate' the privatekey from the certificate, so could an adversary and it would provide no security.

If you received the certificate *newly generated* (by a corporate PKI) in response to *your request*, you must already *have* the privatekey, because the request you sent (called a Certificate Signing Request or CSR) was itself signed using the privatekey. You need to specify what method you used to generate the request, and that will determine where your privatekey is and how to use it.

If you received a certificate generated in response to someone else's request, or initiated by the CA on its own, *they* have the privatekey and you need to obtain it from them.

Note that for the signature on an `.exe` to be of any value, your certificate must be specifically flagged as a code-signing certificate, and issued by a CA that is trusted (on your client machines) to issue such certificates. Make sure the request you or someone submitted specified this.

Comment: thanks dave for your inputs...i have myself raised the request in PkCS10 type..how do i get my private key ?...my certificate is flagged as code signing certificate

Comment: As I said it depends on how you generated the request (and key). *If* you used Windows certmgr (or other Windows-CNG application like IIS or Outlook, but those wouldn't do codesigning), you should *import* the new cert using MMC/Certificates (or just `certmgr.msc`) under "Certificate Enrollment Requests"; that gives you a combined "cert WITH key" entry that `signtool` can use, or you can export to PFX if you really prefer. For any other source, like openssl or java, the instructions would be different.

Comment: I used CertReq tool to generate CSR...i could sign the exe with DigiCertUtility with my .cer file...don't know if this is the right thing to do